# Best way to rename indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, foreign-keys, indexing

I need to script (t-sql) renaming 3 indexes in a production data warehouse.

These 3 indexes are single column indexes that are on top of foreign key columns, i.e. `Index 1 = Foreign Key 1`.

**What is the best way to rename these indexes via a script?**

***What "gotchas" do I have to be weary of?**

I'm aware of sp_rename, is this advisable, or should I drop and re-create the indexes with the new name (time isn't an issue)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sp_rename will work fine and shouldn't break anything unless you have queries somewhere that reference the current name(s) in a query hint.